# Python - long execution time

Tags: python

I created my first Python program and I suspect something is wrong. The execution time of the *testovanie()* method was 2 hour. In Java same code was time 10 min.

The implementation must be in two classes. And the implementation of each algorithm must be as written (if there is no problem).

Can you help me fix the execution time?

**First Class**

```
class Algoritmy:
    """
     The Algorithms class creates an array of Integer numbers. Contains methods for working with the field (sorting).

    """
    def __init__(self, velkostPola):
        """
       Constructor that initializes attributes.

        :param velkostPola: array size.

         """
        self.velkostPola = velkostPola
        self.poleCisel = []


    def nacitajZoSuboru(self, nazov):
        """
         The method reads integer values from a file and writes them to the field.

        :param nazov: a string that contains the name of the file from which the values are read into the field.
        :type nazov: string
        """
        f = open(nazov, 'r+')
        self.poleCisel = f.readlines()
        self.poleCisel = [int(i) for i in self.poleCisel]
        f.close()

    def toString(self):
        """
        A method that serves as a text representation (listing) of the entire array of Numbers fields.

        """
        for x in self.poleCisel:
            print(x)

    def bubbleSort(self):
        """
         The method sorts arrays according to a bubble algorithm with complexity n ^ 2.
         Compares adjacent values if the first value is greater than the second value
         replace them. The algorithm is repeated until it sorts the entire field from the smallest to the largest.

        """
        n = len(self.poleCisel)
        for i in range(0, n):
            for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
                if self.poleCisel[j] > self.poleCisel[j + 1]:
                    self.vymena(j,j+1)

    def insertionSort(self):
        """
        The method classifies the array according to the insertion algorithm with complexity n ^ 2.
         Compares the next value with the previous one and places it after
         a value that is less than. Repeats until it sorts the entire field from
         smallest to largest.
        """
        n = len(self.poleCisel)
        for i in range(n):
            pom = self.poleCisel[i]
            j = i - 1
            while (j >= 0) and (pom < self.poleCisel[j]):
                self.poleCisel[j + 1] = self.poleCisel[j]
                j -= 1
            self.poleCisel[j + 1] = pom

    def quickSort(self, najm, najv):
        """
         The method sorts arrays according to a quick algorithm with complexity n * (log2 n).
         The algorithm chooses the pivot. The elements are so smaller that there are smaller and on the left side
         larger elements on the right.

        :param najm: najmI celociselna lowest index
        :type najm: integer
        :param najv: najvI highest index
        :type najv: integer

        """
        i = najm
        j = najv
        pivot = self.poleCisel[najm + (najv - najm) // 2]
        while i <= j:
            while self.poleCisel[i] < pivot:
                i += 1
            while self.poleCisel[j] > pivot:
                j -= 1
            if i <= j:
                self.vymena(i, j)
                i += 1
                j -= 1
        if najm < j:
            self.quickSort(najm, j)
        if i < najv:
            self.quickSort(i, najv)

    def vymena(self, i, j):
        """
         An auxiliary procedure that ensures the exchange of element i for element j in the array.

        :param i: jeden prvok pola
        :type i: integer
        :param j: druhy prvok pola
        :type j: integer
        """
        pom = self.poleCisel[i]
        self.poleCisel[i] = self.poleCisel[j]
        self.poleCisel[j] = pom

    def selectionSort(self):
        """
        The method classifies the array according to a selection algorithm with complexity n ^ 2.
         The algorithm finds the largest value and exchanges it with the last element. He will find
         always the highest value among unsorted elements and exchanges it with
         the last unsorted element.

        """
        for i in reversed(range(0, len(self.poleCisel))):
            prvy = 0
            for j in range(0, i):
                if self.poleCisel[j] > self.poleCisel[prvy]:
                    prvy = j

            self.vymena(prvy,i)

    def shellSort(self, n):
        """
        The method classifies the array according to a shell algorithm with complexity n ^ 2
         Gradually, the elements distant from each other are compared by a space - at the beginning there is a space = n / 2,
         where n is the size of the field we are sorting. If the left element being compared is larger than the right one being compared,
         so for replacement. Then the gap is reduced and the procedure is repeated.

        :param n: size of array
        :type n: integer

        """
        medzera = n // 2
        while medzera > 0:
            i = medzera
            for i in range(0, n):
                pom = self.poleCisel[i]
                j = i
                while (j >= medzera) and (self.poleCisel[j - medzera] > pom):
                    self.poleCisel[j] = self.poleCisel[j - medzera]
                    j = j - medzera
                self.poleCisel[j] = pom
            medzera = medzera // 2

    def heapSort(self):
        """
         The method sorts arrays according to the heap algorithm with complexity n * (log n).
         The algorithm adds elements to the heap where it stores them at the end of the heap. Unless
         the previous element is larger, then the elements are replaced until it is
         predecessor smaller. This is repeated until a sorted field is created.

        """
        n = len(self.poleCisel)
        for k in reversed(range(1, n // 2)):
            self.maxHeapify(k, n)
        while True:
            self.vymena(0,n-1)
            n = n - 1
            self.maxHeapify(1, n)
            if (n < 1):
                break

    def maxHeapify(self, otecI, n):
        """
         This method serves to preserve the properties of Heap.

        :param otecI: index otca
        :type otecI: integer
        :param n: nastavenie vacsich prvkov
        :type n: integer

        """
        otec = self.poleCisel[otecI - 1]
        while otecI <= n // 2:
            lavySyn = otecI + otecI
            if (lavySyn < n) and (self.poleCisel[lavySyn - 1] < self.poleCisel[lavySyn]):
                lavySyn += 1
            if otec >= self.poleCisel[lavySyn - 1]:
                break
            else:
                self.poleCisel[otecI - 1] = self.poleCisel[lavySyn - 1]
                otecI = lavySyn
        self.poleCisel[otecI - 1] = otec
```

**Second Class**

```
from Algoritmy import Algoritmy
import time

class Praca:



    def __init__(self):
        self.casB = []
        self.casQ = []
        self.casS = []
        self.casI = []
        self.casSh = []
        self.casH = []


    def vypisPriemer(self):
        """
         A method that calculates and prints the averages of the algorithm duration from the time field.

        """
        sumB = 0;sumQ = 0;sumS = 0;sumI = 0;sumSh = 0;sumH = 0
        for j in range(0, 200):
            sumB += self.casB[j]
            sumQ += self.casQ[j]
            sumS += self.casS[j]
            sumI += self.casI[j]
            sumSh += self.casSh[j]
            sumH += self.casH[j]
        priemerB = sumB / 200 
        priemerQ = sumQ / 200
        priemerS = sumS / 200
        priemerI = sumI / 200
        priemerSh = sumSh / 200
        priemerH = sumH / 200
        print("Bubble Sort alg. priemer: %10.9f" %priemerB)
        print("Quick Sort alg. priemer: %10.9f"%priemerQ)
        print("Selection Sort alg. priemer: %10.9f"%priemerS)
        print("Insertion Sort alg. priemer: %10.9f"%priemerI)
        print("Shell Sort alg. priemer: %10.9f"%priemerSh)
        print("Heap Sort alg. priemer: %10.9f"%priemerH)

    def replikacie(self,velkost, nazovS):
        """
        The method is aimed at performing 200 replications for each single algorithm.
         Collects and stores the execution time of the algorithm in the field.

         :param velkost: array size
         :type velkost: integer
         :param nazovS: file name
         :type nazovS: string

        """
        self.casB.clear()
        self.casQ.clear()
        self.casS.clear()
        self.casI.clear()
        self.casSh.clear()
        self.casH.clear()
        praca = Algoritmy(velkost)
        for i in range(0, 200):
            praca.nacitajZoSuboru(nazovS)
            zaciatok=time.time()
            praca.bubbleSort()
            self.casB.append(time.time() - zaciatok)
            praca.nacitajZoSuboru(nazovS)
            zaciatok=time.time()
            praca.quickSort(0, praca.velkostPola-1)
            self.casQ.append(time.time() - zaciatok)
            praca.nacitajZoSuboru(nazovS)
            zaciatok=time.time()
            praca.selectionSort()
            self.casS.append(time.time() - zaciatok)
            praca.nacitajZoSuboru(nazovS)
            zaciatok=time.time()
            praca.insertionSort()
            self.casI.append(time.time() - zaciatok)
            praca.nacitajZoSuboru(nazovS)
            zaciatok=time.time()
            praca.shellSort(praca.velkostPola)
            self.casSh.append(time.time() - zaciatok)
            praca.nacitajZoSuboru(nazovS)
            zaciatok=time.time()
            praca.heapSort()
            self.casH.append(time.time() - zaciatok)

    def testovanie(self):
        """
        Testing

        """
        self.replikacie(10000,"neutr10000.txt")
        print("Neutriedene 10000")
        self.vypisPriemer()

    def main(self):

        zaciatok = time.time()
        self.testovanie()
        print(time.time() - zaciatok)





"""
Run

"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    praca = Praca()
    praca.main()
```

If you have any improvements, don't be shy to tell me, if I said it's my first Python program. Be nice to me :)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Does it work if `testovanie` has a small number of items to sort? And since SO is an English-based site, you must comment the necessary code in English, as well as Slovak.

Comment: @ rajah9 thanks for the comment, I have already adjusted my post to the minimum content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more condensed MRE would make it easier to comment on the specific statements, but my guess is that your example just illustrates that Python *is* slow for certain use cases.

This kind of number crunching in pure-Python loops is the nightmare scenario for Python, at least for the most popular CPython implementation.

There are, however, different ways you could speed this up if you diverge a bit from pure CPython:

- Use [PyPy JIT](https://www.pypy.org/) to run your program instead of CPython. PyPy usually speeds your code ~3-5x, but for numeric stuff like yours you can get an even more impressive speed bump.
- Use numeric libraries to vectorize your code and/or offload common operations to optimized routines (written in C, Fortran or even assembly). [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) is a popular choice.
- Rewrite your program, or at least the "hottest" code paths, in Cython `cdef` functions and classes, see, e.g., https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html.
- You may want to check out [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), but I have no experience with it.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I need to use pure Python in my program. Pypy little helped but it is still slowly against Java or C. What you mean under "number crunching"?? After all is my program rightly writet, and ist just a Python issue or my code is bad?

Comment: I assumed your program to be a some sort of learning exercise, as Python features `list.sort` and `sorted()` methods that implement the "timsort" algorithm efficiently inside the interpreter itself. Other than that, it is mostly a Python issue, particularly a CPython issue. By "number crunching" I mean loops based on an integer counter with many iterations, numeric operations such as arithmetics and comparisons.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in the view of those 2 hours vs 10 minutes, which number did you get on PyPy?